# Save content of code bein executed by test into File

Tags: java, testing

I want to write a program that counts the lines of code being executed when

a test, lets say `TestA()`, runs. More importantly, I need to store the

lines of code being executed

by `TestA()`, into a `codeLines: String`.

I find this concept really bizarre and so far, I did not have any luck with

online resources. Do you know of any way that such functionality could be achieved?

Comment: What exactly do you mean saving into a `codeLines: String`. Are you referring to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand of the question, it seems like the closest functionality that you can easily attain is by using a debugger, which lets you step through lines, step into lines, and see what line is doing what in the code.